# Do Eurostar eVouchers cover both passengers on a booking reference?

Tags: cancellations, eurostar

My wife and I had a booking on the Eurostar from London to Brussels, I just visited their web site and cancelled the reservation since our entire trip to Europe will have to be rescheduled.

I could only use my name and the six letter booking reference when cancelling to get the eVoucher, I'd like to get confirmation that my wife's ticket will be included since the booking reference is the same for her.  It seems reasonable, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: What did Eurostar say when you asked them?

Comment: This is all being done online.  I'd like to avoid trying to talk to a warm body, since they are probably run off their feet right now dealing with other passengers that want to change / cancel their trips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they don't. Each voucher is for one passenger as mentioned on [Eurostar's website](https://www.eurostar.com/us-en/travel-info/service-information/coronavirus-and-eurostar-service):

> ## Giving you the flexibility to change your travel plans
>
> We will offer you an eVoucher equivalent to the full value of your current Eurostar train or Eurostar package (train + hotel)  booking. You can use this eVoucher online to make a new booking by 30 September 2020, to travel to any Eurostar destination up to the end of March 2021 (subject to availability).
>
> **You’ll receive separate vouchers for each passenger on your booking. For return journeys, you’ll receive separate vouchers per person for each part of the trip.**

I recommend checking that you didn't receive two vouchers or contacting Eurostar.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate this is too late for the OP now but you do not have to accept their offer of vouchers as if they cancel your train you are entitles to a full refund. Here is what you have to do:

Visit https://prr.eurostar.com after your train has been cancelled (leave at least 24 hours before you try).

If this fails and it is very busy at the moment then:

Escalate to traveller.care@eurostar.com or via their contact form which ends up going to contactus@eurostar.com and mention their conditions of carriage article 32.2.3 available [here](https://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/conditions-carriage)

It may take some time after you have succeeded for them to actually issue the refund to your payment card.

This succeeded for me but if it fails for you the last resource is to contact the relevant national enforcement body ORR in the UK DGCCRF in France and SPF in Belgium but that really should not be necessary.